# Typescript: get type of first property of type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I get a nested object as result of a GraphQL query with the query name as first-level key and the actual data on the second level:

```
{
    getProduct: {
        id: "1",
        name: "test",
    }
}
```

In my query function I automatically extract the first key of the object and return the value of `getProduct`. However, I would like to infer the type of the first key as the return value of the query function.

```
type QueryReturn = FirstElement<GetProductQuery>; // should be { id: string; name: string }
```

All solutions I've found on the Internet infer the Head or Tail of an Array or Function.

Comment: What is the “first” key? How do you get it?  Keys in TypeScript object types are unordered so there’s likely no (consistent non-fragile) way to do this.

Comment: With first key I mean the result of `Object.keys(data)[0]`. I was hoping I could extract all keys as an array (instead of a string union) and then simply take the first element of that array.

Comment: Keys in TypeScript object types are not ordered; see [this example](https://tsplay.dev/NVKy7m); the compiler simply cannot guarantee that keys will come in any particular order.  This is not possible in TypeScript, nor should you try to do this unless you have very tight control over the data coming in.  Why do you have any functionality that depends on key ordering of an object?  Seems iffy to me.  What's the use case?  You aren't showing something even two keys in it so it's hard to know what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit late to the party but I saw that you were using [graphql-codegen](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/). I had a similar problem which I solved with:

```
type DataType = {
  __typename?: string;
};

type FilteredQuery<T> = {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends DataType ? P : never]: T[P];
};

type QueryData<T> = FilteredQuery<T>[keyof FilteredQuery<T>];
```

TypeScript playground [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOAVc0C8UDeBYAUFKAfUNEgDs4BbCAfgC4oBnYAJwEsyBzAbjwF9euPKWgAxNgBtgEFhAAmARQCuMkAB4kAPigYc+KAG0AClA5QA1hBAB7AGZQkUOIwfGAulAgAPaWTkv4RBRIKBooEwYyCAA3GTcGJHdBATxhVChlVUC4DW0McSkZeUyWdS0DSxt7AulZRRVS3LdBPAB6VqgAUS8qMAkIPG8waxZgKBEoAFVGGRKQHSwoPAJiEQpqeigAcjmtgBol-SUZlgZMQ4IVklR12gYt6Zl95cu2OQZmdi5BS6hjmVuH1YHB4Lz4-BauAmjxYc2yCzhCByMLmmm4QA).

Answer (score 1):

Bit late. if you can assure that you always have single key in the outmost type, you can do it by utilizing `keyof` operator and indexed access type.

This will behave strangely if you have no keys or more than one key in the outmost type, so make sure you *always* have the exact one key in all scenario.

Example:

```js
type Unwrap<T> = T[keyof T];

type QueryReturn = Unwrap<GetProductQuery>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgdwE4EMwB4AqA+KBeKTAbQGsIQB7AM0IF0BuAWACgWB6NqAUQA8UBbMABsILCDzAUkwKKEhQA4hGAAFJBQAmAVwDGwAIpaISEPigBvKCyhQA5srWbdwAFwXrNzwEsNbuFv4AI2MAGg9PKDgBCDcAZ2AkLzhbMOYbAF8WdKZWZg4oAAkKADdjWQALaGChCgRZcGhgCihYiEbKqHEElD0IDXrIFjloJVV1bT1DYxAAERRgFDN4ZDR0UccJgyMTbHogA)

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding correctly that you just want to get to the product type without the `getProduct` alias in the middle?

I get the hunch this extra level is there because you are aliasing your query. Regardless, there is no first key in an object. The way to drill down would be to specify the key. This can all be made much easier by auto-generating types with a tool like [graphql-autogen](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/installation).

Comment: I'm already using graphql-codegen to generate all Query and Mutation types and they all contain the name of the query/mutation as the first field in the structure.

Comment: Your comment changes nothing with regard to the answer posted here. A single client query can include multiple server root queries and even multiple of the same root queries. They are automatically aliased by the name of the query., Traditionally, your query name would include no verb, so your query response type might be `{ product: Product, user: User }`.

Am I understanding you want the query response type to strip off all but one query response?

Comment: I want to overwrite the return type of certain generated `getQuery` types to return the value of the aliased field `{ getProductQuery: { id: '', ... } }`